# Matlab Error when Passing Image from Console - Basic

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying pass a .png image from the console in matlab to a function called bwconversion. The function I have written does work when I assign the a variable name to the image file in the console screen - i.e.:

```
>>a = imread('1.png');
>>bwconversion(a);
```

However I need the code to work whereas I can pass it the file path directly such as:

```
>>bwconversion('J:\Vision\ColourIm\1.png');
```

But the above returns errors indicating the image was not passed to the function?

Please find my very basic function below:

```
function bwconversion(imIn)

%Convert Image to Black and White
gr = rgb2gray(imIn);
bw = im2bw(gr, 0.04);
clear gr;
imshow(bw);
```

I'll be grateful for any advice that can be offered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply pass the file name as the parameter?

```
function bwconversion(imIn_name)

% Read the image
imIn = imread(imIn_name);

% Convert Image to Black and White
gr = rgb2gray(imIn);
bw = im2bw(gr, 0.04);
clear gr;
imshow(bw);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this still gives me identical errors:

Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 81)
MAP must be a m x 3 array.

Error in rgb2gray (line 35)
X = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in bwconversion (line 4)
gr = rgb2gray(imIn);

Comment: @L1am22 your image is probably already BW. The error tells you `imIN` must have 3 channels (last dimension of `imIN` must be 3). Type `size(imIN)` before the call to `rgb2gray` to see what data you have.

Comment: I've just moved computers in the Lab and it looks as though it was a faulty installation of MatLab as the code you have provided and the code I originally uploaded both compile without errors. Apologies to have wasted your time.